# Context value not being read

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat9

I have the following entry in my context.xml:

```
<Environment name="environment" value="DEV" type="java.lang.String" override="false" />
```

And a servlet that calls for that -

```
        try
        {
            Context initContext = new InitialContext();
            environment = (String) initContext.lookup("environment");
        }
        catch (final NamingException nx)
        {
            ERROR_RECORDER.error(nx.getMessage(), nx);
        }
```

Now, the code works. I can run it in other containers and it's fine. This is only happening under Tomcat 9.0.73, and according to the Tomcat docs I have this configured correctly, but I'm getting the following exception:

```
[Time: 16 Mar 2023 06:36:36,840][Thread: main][Log: ERROR_RECORDER.][Level: ERROR] - [File: ResponseTimeFilter.java:80] - Name [environment] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [environment].
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [environment] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [environment].
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem... I didn't have an

```
Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
```

It would seem that IBM WebSphere Application Server (our primary application server) adds this information for you...

my mistake.